# In a 2-connected graph find minimum no of edges

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

What is the minimum number of edges required for a $2$-connected graph?

I tried in this way:

We know that 
$\;\;\;\; \begin{align*}
\kappa(G) \leq \text{ min-degree} \leq \frac{2\cdot e}{n}
\end{align*}
$ where $\kappa(G)$ is vertex connectivity. Therefore for $\kappa(G) = 2 \;\; $ we have $\;\; e \geq n$.

Is my argument valid?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your argument correctly shows that $e\geq n$. To complete the problem, you also need to give an example of a $2$-connected graph with exactly this number of edges, to show that you don't need more than $n$. (What you've done implies that such a graph must have every degree equal to $2$.)

Comment: If I take a cycle graph with four vertices. Then it is 2-connected and no of edges is also 4. Is it enough or do I need a more formal method?

Comment: @Debashish You could take that idea and use induction to go from there. Basically, every polygon has the same number of sides and vertices and satisfies 2-connectivity in both edges and vertices.